# How to make the value of the progress bar visible when hovering

Tags: html

It will probably be very simple though I cannot find a proper solution for my problem.
What I want is the following, when a user hovers over the progressbar, the progress bar gives the value of progressbar in a small popup screen or something like that. You can probably figure out what I am trying to say :)

my html5 code:

```
<progress id="progressBar" value="50" max="100"></progress>
```

I am very noob at html 5 and the hover thingy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do it with simple CSS using `attr()` and pseudo element.

HTML:

```
<progress id="progressBar" value="50" max="100"></progress>
```

CSS:

```
progress#progressBar:hover:after {
    display: block;
    content: attr(value);
}
```

​

Here is working example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LE4X4/1/)

You can style this pseudo element, so it will look like "popup screen" or whatever you want ;-)

Comment: Is it possible to display it inside the middle of the progressbar?

Comment: Yes, simple `width:100%; text-align:center` should do the trick. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LE4X4/2/)

Comment: I have this #progressBar{
 appearance: none;
 -moz-appearance: none;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 
 }
To have a simple look, but when I add this css rule the "pop-up" is displayed onder the progressbar. How come? (i found that at a website)

Comment: That is weird. But it can be fixed with absolute positioning; set `position: relative` to progress, and `position:absolute; top:0;` to pseudo element. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LE4X4/3/)

Comment: Man you are the best!
I added this myself now: content: attr(value) "/" attr(max);
So it is now exactly how I want it, thanks mate!

Answer (score 4):

#### Use `:before`

```
progress#progressBar:hover:before {
    display: inline;
    content: attr(value);
}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U58Tp/

Comment: Thanks!
Is it possible to display it inside the middle of the progressbar?

Comment: Yeah, just give `text-align: center;`

Comment: @LoveRight Are you referring to an answer that was posted 5 years ago? `:O`

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit inelegant but it works.
Attach `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` scripts to the progress bar to show and hide a `div`. It can be placed and styled as desired.

```
<progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" 
 onmouseover="a=document.getElementById('stat');
              a.innerHTML=this.value; 
              a.style.display='block'" 
 onmouseout="document.getElementById('stat').style.display='none'">
</progress>
<div id="stat"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort but the other 2 options are more doable for me :p

Comment: Fair enough. They look better to me, too, but weren't working for me in Firefox.

Comment: Hadn't tested it in firefox but you are right! I do might consider yours too! thanks